# Insert date time value into SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, winforms

I'm trying to insert date time picker value into a `DATETIME` column in my database.

Here's my code..

```
 myconstr = "Data Source=wind;Initial Catalog=TestDB;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False";
 myquery = "INSERT INTO DateTimeTB(MyDate) VALUES (@mydate)";

 using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(myconstr))
 {
     SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(myquery);
     cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
     cmd.Connection = connection;
     cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@mydate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = MyDTP01.Value);
     connection.Open();
     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
     connection.Close();
 }
```

It gives me the following error..

> The SQL parameter collection only accepts non-null SqlParameter type objects, not date time objects.

How can I fix this..?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code is equivalent to:

```
var parameter = new SqlParameter("@mydate", SqlDbType.DateTime);
var value = MyDTP01.Value;
parameter.Value = value;
cmd.Parameters.Add(value);
```

You want to add the *parameter*, not the value. So:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@mydate", SqlDbType.DateTime)).Value = MyDTP01.Value;
```

Note the location of the brackets.

This can be simplified, however - you don't need to call the `SqlParameter` constructor yourself - you can just pass the name and the type to `Add`:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@mydate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = MyDTP01.Value;
```

Comment: Unless `MyDTP01.Value` is neither `DateTime` nor `DateTime?`, this is a bit unwieldy.  `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mydate", MyDTP01.Value);` and `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mydate", MyDTP01.Value ?? SqlDateTime.Null);`, respectively, are simpler.

Comment: @Brian: I prefer to explicitly state the parameter type, personally.

Comment: It just feels awkward to me to leverage the return value of `Add`, though presumably that's what it's for.  Maybe a compromise with `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mydate", new SqlDateTime(MyDTP01.Value));`? I admit this won't work if `MyDTP01.Value` is, for example, a `string`, but I consider that a net positive.

Comment: @Brian: I'd still rather use the pattern in my answer. I agree it's a little odd the first time you see it - but after that, it explains exactly what you mean with very little fuss.

Answer (score -1):

Using Enterprise Library, This is how I do it

```
 var db = EnterpriseLibraryContainer.Current.GetInstance<Database>();
 using( DbCommand command = db.GetStoredProcCommand("Your Stored proc name"))
 {
   db.AddInParameter(command, "@mydate", DbType.DateTime, DateTime.Now.Date); // Replace with MyDTP01.Value
   db.ExecuteNonQuery(command);
 }
```

Comment: There's nothing in here that won't work identically with regular ADO.NET; heck, `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("mydate", DateTime.Now.Date);` would work just as easily, without needing ent-lib (which is, in my considered professional opinion - a very badly architected library)